# cannot run `:normal s<CR>` just for nerdtree (opens file vertically splitted)

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript

what im trying to achieve:

- use `<C-V>` to paste text in normal mode in current buffer
- use same `<C-V>` to vertically split a file from nerdtree

what i know:

- when you are with your cursor in nerdtree and you press the letter `s`, it will split the file under cursor vertically ( from docs: `" s: open vsplit`)

what i tried:

- `:normal s` from nerdtree buffer, and `it worked` like a charm.

in init.vim i have this:

```
" this function works, i tried it many times
function IsCurrentWindowNERDTree()
  return exists("t:NERDTreeBufName") && bufwinnr(t:NERDTreeBufName) == winnr()
endfunction

function Control_v_key_binding()
    if IsCurrentWindowNERDTree()
        " problem is here !!!
        normal s
    else
        " this just pastes the text from os clipboard
        normal "+p 
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap <C-V> :call Control_v_key_binding()<CR>
inoremap <C-V> <C-O>:call Control_v_key_binding()<CR>
```

in function, i tried:

- execute "normal \s"
- normal \s
- normal s

i mapped `nnoremap <C-N> :normal s<CR>` for control+N and it worked.

```
function Control_v_key_binding()
    if IsCurrentWindowNERDTree()
        normal s
    else
        normal "+p
    endif
endfunction

" this is really stupid, this configuration works flawlessly
nnoremap <C-N> :call Control_v_key_binding()<CR>

" and this doesnt work
nnoremap <C-V> :call Control_v_key_binding()<CR>
```

some weird part, i debugged this function and it just wont enter in the first `if`, goes automatically on `else`, but works on every other case for other keybindings, my function `IsCurrentWindowNERDTree` works everytime ; i binded `nnoremap <C-V> :normal s<CR>`, doesnt work either.

i dont understand what is wrong with `<C-V>`

any ideas? thanks

Comment: This is not an answer to your question but a friendly advice from someone who has been messing with NERDTree in the past: You are not doing yourself any favor trying to use NERDTree, bending it to your needs always creates frustration and hacky workarounds (also have a look [here](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/01/oil-and-vinegar-split-windows-and-project-drawer/)) also remapping `<C-v>` to paste text is a great way to cause issues in the future: `<C-v>` is super useful for visual block selection and not pasting with `p` leads to all kind of troubles (using different registers, `p`vs`P`,etc)

Comment: So once you debug your problem (which you should still do because that's a good learning opportunity) I real encourage you to ditch at least your `<C-v>` mapping and also to replace NERDTree with the built-in netrw, `:ls`, `:b`, `:find, etc and maybe a fuzzy finder if you really need one.

Comment: my entire question is debugging my problem. i understand that some people dont like nerdtree because they realised that is worthless, for me its useful. i already have `fzf`, i just like nerd tree standing alone there in the left. i solved the problem my selecting another keybinding, but i `really wanted` to use `C-V` and to find out what wrong with C-V, because there is something wrong, otherwise `C-N` wouldnt work also.

Comment: Of course that's why I said my comment wasn't answering your question and it was just a piece of unsolicited advice. I'm sure someone else will be more useful and will help you actually debugging that :)

Comment: honestly, i dont care anymore. its too much of a pain. i've found another key binding for that, and voilla, problem solved, but if someone smarter comes around and gives me the answer to why C-V has problems in vim, thanks.